# Link error while drawing an Ellipse - MASM32

Tags: graphics, linker-errors, masm32

here's a piece of code:

```
WndProc proc hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM
    LOCAL hdc:HDC
    LOCAL ps:PAINTSTRUCT
    LOCAL rect:RECT
    .IF uMsg==WM_DESTROY
        invoke PostQuitMessage, NULL
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_PAINT
        invoke BeginPaint, hWnd, ADDR ps
        mov hdc, eax
        invoke GetClientRect, hWnd, ADDR rect
        invoke Ellipse, hdc, 100, 100, 300, 200
        invoke DrawText, hdc, ADDR name, -1, ADDR rect,\
            DT_SINGLELINE or DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER
        invoke EndPaint, hWnd, ADDR ps
     .ELSE
        invoke DefWindowProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam
        ret
    .ENDIF
    xor eax,eax
    ret

   WndProc endp
```

in that piece I put on the screen some name and an ellipse. but when I try to build it linker says:

```
only.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Ellipse@20
only.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

what am I doing wrong? I tried to put `invoke Ellipse` somewhere else but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I got it: I forgot to include gdi32.lib:

```
includelib \MASM32\LIB\gdi32.lib
```